# JPA: Query on point of exception thrown?

Tags: jpa, transactions

In my test JPA project, I am doing following:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAExamples");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();        
    Article article = em.find(Article.class, 1);
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(21);
    comment.setAuthor("Author21");
    comment.setTitle("Title21");
    comment.setArticle(article);
    em.persist(comment);        
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

Comment with id 21 is already there in DB(MySQL).And hence I get EntityExistsException. But my concern is the line where I get it.I get it on em.persist(). AFAIK, persistent context would sync with DB only when I do em.getTransaction().commit().EntityExistsException can only be realised when provider hits DB which happens on commit(). em.persist() should only make Comment object managed i.e registered with persistent context. So why do I get exception on em.persist()and not on em.getTransaction().commit()

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadocs for EntityManager.persist

```
@throws EntityExistsException if the entity already exists.
(If the entity already exists, the EntityExistsException may
be thrown when the persist operation is invoked, or the
EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException may be
thrown at flush or commit time.)
```

It's up to the implementation to decide when it does checks.